# How to bind dynamic checkboxes to id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, dynamic-binding, criteria-filter

I have a couple of checkboxes which I dynamically create trough an iteration. In want to use these to trigger a function.

My issue is when I select/check 1 checkbox all the others get checked instandly. I want to be able to check and uncheck them individually.

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="name" type="string" /> 
<aura:attribute name="text" type="string" /> 
<aura:attribute name="value" type="string"/> 
<aura:attribute name="selectedvalues" type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="SelectedCity" type="List[]" />
<aura:attribute name="CheckboxValue" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.allaccounts}" indexVar="indx">
    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" value="{!v.CheckboxValue}" text="{!a.BillingCity}" name="{!indx}" label="{!a.BillingCity}" change="{!c.selectoptionvalue}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Javascript

```
 var check = event.getSource().set("v.checkbox");
    var SelectedCity = [];
    if(event.getSource().get("v.CheckboxValue") == true){
        SelectedCity.push({'ids':event.getSource().get("v.name"),'name':event.getSource().get("v.text"),'CheckboxValue':event.getSource().get("v.CheckboxValue")});}

    if(event.getSource().get("v.CheckboxValue") == false){
        for(var j=0;j<SelectedCity.length;j++){
            if(SelectedCity[j].ids == event.getSource().get("v.name")){
                var index = j;
            }
        }
        SelectedCity.splice(index,1);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected; you've bound all the checkboxes to a single value. Instead, you need to create a wrapper, and check/uncheck individual values:

```
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" 
                  value="{!a.selected}" 
                  text="{!a.record.BillingCity}" 
                  name="{!indx}" 
                  label="{!a.record.BillingCity}" 
                  change="{!c.selectoptionvalue}"/>
```

From there, to populate your list of selected cities, just build a new list:

```
selectoptionvalue: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.set("v.SelectedCity",
    component.get("v.allaccounts").filter(account => account.selected)
  );
}
```

---

Edit: Demo application that uses aura:id.

---

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="allaccounts" type="List" default="[ { BillingCity: 'Denver' }, { BillingCity: 'Ontario' }, { BillingCity: 'San Francisco' } ]" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedCities" type="List" default="[]" />

    <aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.allaccounts}" indexVar="indx">
        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" 
                          text="{!a.BillingCity}"
                          name="{!indx}"
                          label="{!a.BillingCity}" 
                          change="{!c.selectoptionvalue}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
    <hr />
    Selections: {!join(',',v.selectedCities)}
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    selectoptionvalue: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selected = [], checkboxes = component.find("checkbox");
        if(!checkboxes) {   // Find returns zero values when there's no items
            checkboxes = [];
        } else if(!checkboxes.length) { // Find returns a normal object with one item
            checkboxes = [checkboxes];
        }
        checkboxes
        .filter(checkbox => checkbox.get("v.value"))    // Get only checked boxes
        .forEach(checkbox => selected.push(checkbox.get("v.label")));   // And get the labels
        component.set("v.selectedCities", selected);    // Set to display
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit further on this as why not binding the aura:id. And how do I output this result directly to the current screen output?

Comment: @Thomas If you want to use aura:id, then you'd need to "find" the checkboxes and examine the results. I added a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) for you to look over.

Comment: I am very very appreciative of your concise explanation. Thanks in a million to explain this. You always take time to explain! THANKS.

Comment: @Thomas You're welcome! Glad I could help you out.

Comment: @sfdcfox Could you please explain more about the "filter" function? Haven't seen much information about this in the developer document.

Comment: @the_phantom It uses a function to filter values in the list. You can read more on the MDN: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: @sfdcfox I am trying to comprehend the last example. If I would like to show all the accounts with the same City when the checkbox is checked what would the annotation be in javascript?